# What camera communication standards are used by Navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia()?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediadevices

Does anyone know what communication standards are being used to detect camera hardware for use with getUserMedia?

I presume that it's MTP or something like that, although I expect that the implementation is different for each browser/OS, but I've been searching for two days and I can't find any solid information on this.

Comment: If you are talking only about hardware detection protocol then I think you are right. Each Browser uses methods defined in particular OS to access camera hardware. But if you are looking to media transport protocols used in ``WebRTC`` then you can go through https://www.innoarchitech.com/what-is-webrtc-and-how-does-it-work/, https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/.

Answer (score 7):

I have long time searched for the answer of your question. At first I found this on [w3.org WebRTC site](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/):

> This document defines a set of ECMAScript APIs in WebIDL to allow media to be sent to and received from another browser or device implementing the appropriate set of real-time protocols. This specification is being developed in conjunction with a *protocol specification developed by the IETF RTCWEB group* and an *API specification to get access to **local media devices** developed by the Media Capture Task Force*.

Then on the site ["Media transport and use of RTP"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-rtcweb-rtp-usage/?include_text=1) I have found following informations:

> **5.2.4.  Media Stream Identification:**
>
> WebRTC endpoints that implement the SDP bundle negotiation extension
>   will use the SDP grouping framework 'mid' attribute to identify media
>   streams. Such endpoints MUST implement the RTP MID header extension
>   described in [I-D.ietf-mmusic-sdp-bundle-negotiation].
>
> This header extension uses the [RFC5285] generic header extension
>   framework, and so needs to be negotiated before it can be used.
>
> **12.2.1.  Media Source Identification:**
>
> Each RTP packet stream is identified by a unique synchronisation
>   source (SSRC) identifier.  The SSRC identifier is carried in each of
>   the RTP packets comprising a RTP packet stream, and is also used to
>   identify that stream in the corresponding RTCP reports.  The SSRC is
>   chosen as discussed in Section 4.8.  The first stage in demultiplexing
>   RTP and RTCP packets received on a single transport layer flow at a
>   WebRTC Endpoint is to separate the RTP packet streams based on their
>   SSRC value; once that is done, additional demultiplexing steps can
>   determine how and where to render the media.
>
> RTP allows a mixer, or other RTP-layer middlebox, to combine encoded
>   streams from multiple media sources to form a new encoded stream from
>   a new media source (the mixer).  The RTP packets in that new RTP
>   packet stream can include a Contributing Source (CSRC) list,
>   indicating which original SSRCs contributed to the combined source
>   stream.
>
> As described in Section 4.1, implementations need to support reception
>   of RTP data packets containing a CSRC list and RTCP packets that
>   relate to sources present in the CSRC list.  The CSRC list can change
>   on a packet-by-packet basis, depending on the mixing operation being
>   performed.
>
> Knowledge of what media sources contributed to a particular RTP packet
>   can be important if the user interface indicates which participants
>   are active in the session. Changes in the CSRC list included in
>   packets needs to be exposed to the WebRTC application using some API,
>   if the application is to be able to track changes in session
>   participation.  It is desirable to map CSRC values back into WebRTC
>   MediaStream identities as they cross this API, to avoid exposing the
>   SSRC/CSRC name space to WebRTC applications.
>
> If the mixer-to-client audio level extension [RFC6465] is being used
>   in the session (see Section 5.2.3), the information in the CSRC list
>   is augmented by audio level information for each contributing source.
>   It is desirable to expose this information to the WebRTC application
>   using some API, after mapping the CSRC values to WebRTC MediaStream
>   identities, so it can be exposed in the user interface.
>
> Perkins, et al.       Expires September 18, 2016  [Page 35]
>
> Internet-Draft        RTP for WebRTC          March 2016

All Transports for WebRTC are listed on [this site](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-rtcweb-transports/?include_text=1).

All documents from IETF RTCWEB group you can find on site ["Real-Time Communication in WEB-browsers (rtcweb)"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/rtcweb/documents/).

---

**For further information:**

- [Media Capture (with links to all documents)](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Media_Capture)
- [MediaStream API (all methods which are used in this API)](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/)
- [Real-time Transport Protocol (RTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol)
- [Session Description Protocol (SDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol)

---

*My conclusion:*

1. Session Description Protocol (SDP)
2. Real Time Transport Protocol (RTP) (may be too)

Answer (score 4):

The webrtc.org library has a set of platform-specific glue modules which can be found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/modules/video_capture/) and also in the [Chrome tree](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/media/capture/video/).
On Windows this uses the MediaFoundation APIs (with a fallback to DirectShow), video4linux on Linux and AVFoundation on Mac